# php symfony user_call_func on object (non static)

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

i'm trying to call a getter of an object dynamically (the getter is in a string) but it won't work:

```
$getterName = "get" . $name; //creation of the getter name like getFirstname
$value = call_user_func(array($player, $getterName()));
```

$player is an instance of myBundle\Entity\Player
I'm running this code in a controller of another symfony bundle.

My error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException: "Attempted to call function "getFirstname" from the global namespace."
```

I don't know how to solve this, does someone have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$getterName()` you're calling a global function: `getFirstname`. If you want call the `getFirstname` method of the `myBundle\Entity\Player` class, then you need to call it with:

```
$value = call_user_func(array($player, $getterName));
```

Comment: I tried and it worked. I didn't know that, thanks for your help